# Create new column by doing specific calculation on the given dictionary in pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame as shown below

```
Session     slot_num
s1          1
s1          2
s1          3
s1          4
s2          1
s2          2
s3          1
s3          2
s3          3
```

And also a dictionary called session_start_time

```
session_start_time = {'s1':'2020-01-06 09:00:00','s2':'2020-08-06 06:00:00','s3':'2020-9-06 19:00:00'}
```

From that I would like prepare below data frame

Expected Output:

```
Session     slot_num   ideal_appt_time
s1          1          2020-01-06 09:00:00
s1          2          2020-01-06 09:20:00
s1          3          2020-01-06 09:40:00
s1          4          2020-01-06 10:00:00
s2          1          2020-08-06 06:00:00
s2          2          2020-08-06 06:20:00
s3          1          2020-09-06 19:00:00
s3          2          2020-09-06 19:20:00
s3          3          2020-09-06 19:40:00
```

Explanation:
select start time of each session from the given dictionary keep that for the first slot of that session then add 20 minutes based on the slot_number of that session.

I tried below code:

```
counts = df.groupby('Session').cumcount()  
td = pd.to_timedelta(counts, unit='Min') * 20
df['ideal_appt_time'] = session_start_time[df.groupby('Session')] + td
# number the slot for each session
df['slot_num'] = counts + 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) for datetimes Series, then add converted column `slot_num` to timedeltas by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) with subtract `1` for start by `0` and multiple by `20` for range by 20 minutes:

```
df['ideal_appt_time'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['Session'].map(session_start_time))
                           .add(pd.to_timedelta(df['slot_num'].sub(1).mul(20), unit='Min')))
print (df)
  Session  slot_num     ideal_appt_time
0      s1         1 2020-01-06 09:00:00
1      s1         2 2020-01-06 09:20:00
2      s1         3 2020-01-06 09:40:00
3      s1         4 2020-01-06 10:00:00
4      s2         1 2020-08-06 06:00:00
5      s2         2 2020-08-06 06:20:00
6      s3         1 2020-09-06 19:00:00
7      s3         2 2020-09-06 19:20:00
8      s3         3 2020-09-06 19:40:00
```

If column `slot_num` is not possible use alternative solution with [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter:

```
counts = df.groupby('Session').cumcount().mul(20)
df['ideal_appt_time'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['Session'].map(session_start_time))
                           .add(pd.to_timedelta(counts, unit='Min')))
print (df)
  Session  slot_num     ideal_appt_time
0      s1         1 2020-01-06 09:00:00
1      s1         2 2020-01-06 09:20:00
2      s1         3 2020-01-06 09:40:00
3      s1         4 2020-01-06 10:00:00
4      s2         1 2020-08-06 06:00:00
5      s2         2 2020-08-06 06:20:00
6      s3         1 2020-09-06 19:00:00
7      s3         2 2020-09-06 19:20:00
8      s3         3 2020-09-06 19:40:00
```

Comment: pls look into below question during your free time. No one answered
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62408422/create-a-function-to-create-new-rows-in-data-frames-based-on-the-given-parameter?noredirect=1#comment110377404_62408422

Comment: @Danish - Sorry, I was offline

Comment: No problem. Thank you so much for your reply.. You are very kind person. God bless you

Comment: pls look into below question during your free time.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63236080/replace-the-column-values-based-on-the-list-of-dictionary-and-specific-date-cond

No one answered