# create a function to create new rows in data frames based on the given parameters as list and specific conditions in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a data frame as shown below. where the data always will have one session. That means number of unique value in a column 'Session' will be one always.

df:

```
  B_ID   No_Show   Session  slot_num  Cumulative_no_show
    1     0.4       S1        1       0.4   
    2     0.3       S1        2       0.7      
    3     0.8       S1        3       1.5        
    4     0.3       S1        4       1.8       
    5     0.6       S1        5       2.4         
    6     0.8       S1        6       3.2       
    7     0.9       S1        7       4.1        
    8     0.4       S1        8       4.5
    9     0.6       S1        9       5.1
```

I tried below code to create above df.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'B_ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 
                   'No_Show': [0.4, 0.3, 0.8, 0.3, 0.6, 0.8, 0.9, 0.4, 0.6], 
                   'Session': ['s1', 's1', 's1', 's1', 's1', 's1', 's1', 's1', 's1'], 
                   'slot_num': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 
                   'Cumulative_no_show': [0.4, 0.7, 1.5, 1.8, 2.4, 3.2, 4.1, 4.5, 5.1]})

df['Cumulative_no_show'] = df.groupby(['Session'])['No_Show'].cumsum()
```

also I have a list called which can be of any length here it is 9.

```
walkin_no_show = [ 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 0.7, 0.8]
```

And I have a another list called is of length 4

```
threshold_p = [0.8, 0.9, 1.0, 1.1]
```

From the above when ever u_cumulative > threshold_p[j] create a new row just below that with

```
 df[No_Show] = walkin_no_show[i]
```

and its Session and slot_num should be same as previous one and create a new column called u_cumulative by subtracting (1 - walkin_no_show[i]) from the previous.

I would like create a fuction called overbook_dfs

```
def overbook_dfs (df, walkin_no_show, threshold_p ):
     return df_0_8, df_0_9, df_1_0, df_1_1
```

where the expected output dfs are shown below:

Expected output:

```
df_0_8:

  B_ID   No_Show   Session  slot_num  Cumulative_no_show   u_cumulative
    1     0.4       S1        1       0.4                  0.4
    2     0.3       S1        2       0.7                  0.7   
    3     0.8       S1        3       1.5                  1.5
walkin1   0.3       S1        3       1.5                  0.8
    4     0.3       S1        4       1.8                  1.1
walkin2   0.2       S1        4       1.8                  0.3      
    5     0.6       S1        5       2.4                  0.9
walkin3   0.1       S1        5       2.4                  0.0         
    6     0.8       S1        6       3.2                  0.8       
    7     0.9       S1        7       4.1                  1.7
walkin4   0.4       S1        7       4.1                  1.1
walkin5   0.5       S1        7       4.1                  0.6
    8     0.4       S1        8       4.5                  1.0
walkin6   0.4       S1        8       4.5                  0.4
    9     0.6       S1        9       5.1                  1.0
walkin7   0.2       S1        8       5.1                  0.2
```

df_0_9:

```
  B_ID   No_Show   Session  slot_num  Cumulative_no_show   u_cumulative
    1     0.4       S1        1       0.4                  0.4
    2     0.3       S1        2       0.7                  0.7   
    3     0.8       S1        3       1.5                  1.5
walkin1   0.3       S1        3       1.5                  0.8
    4     0.3       S1        4       1.8                  1.1
walkin2   0.2       S1        4       1.8                  0.3      
    5     0.6       S1        5       2.4                  0.9        
    6     0.8       S1        6       3.2                  1.7
walkin3   0.1       S1        6       3.2                  0.8       
    7     0.9       S1        7       4.1                  1.7
walkin4   0.4       S1        7       4.1                  1.1
walkin5   0.5       S1        7       4.1                  0.6    
    8     0.4       S1        8       4.5                  1.0
walkin6   0.4       S1        8       4.5                  0.4    
    9     0.6       S1        9       5.1                  1.0
walkin7   0.2       S1        9       5.1                  0.2
```

df_1_0:

```
  B_ID   No_Show   Session  slot_num  Cumulative_no_show   u_cumulative
    1     0.4       S1        1       0.4                  0.4
    2     0.3       S1        2       0.7                  0.7   
    3     0.8       S1        3       1.5                  1.5
walkin1   0.3       S1        3       1.5                  0.8
    4     0.3       S1        4       1.8                  1.1
walkin2   0.2       S1        4       1.8                  0.3      
    5     0.6       S1        5       2.4                  0.9        
    6     0.8       S1        6       3.2                  1.7
walkin3   0.1       S1        6       3.2                  0.8       
    7     0.9       S1        7       4.1                  1.7
walkin4   0.4       S1        7       4.1                  1.1
walkin5   0.5       S1        7       4.1                  0.6    
    8     0.4       S1        8       4.5                  1.1
walkin6   0.4       S1        8       4.5                  0.5
    9     0.6       S1        9       5.1                  1.1
walkin7   0.4       S1        9       4.5                  1.0
```

df_1_1:

```
  B_ID   No_Show   Session  slot_num  Cumulative_no_show   u_cumulative
    1     0.4       S1        1       0.4                  0.4
    2     0.3       S1        2       0.7                  0.7   
    3     0.8       S1        3       1.5                  1.5
walkin1   0.3       S1        3       1.5                  0.8
    4     0.3       S1        4       1.8                  1.1      
    5     0.6       S1        5       2.4                  1.6
walkin2   0.2       S1        5       2.4                  0.8        
    6     0.8       S1        6       3.2                  1.6
walkin3   0.1       S1        6       3.2                  0.7       
    7     0.9       S1        7       4.1                  1.6
walkin4   0.4       S1        7       4.1                  1.0
    8     0.4       S1        8       4.5                  1.4
walkin5   0.5       S1        8       4.5                  0.9
    9     0.6       S1        9       5.1                  1.5
walkin6   0.2       S1        9       5.1                  0.7
```

I have raised similar question which is answered by @Ben.T. Thank you so much @Ben.T. The link of this question is shown below.
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62408422/create-a-function-to-create-new-rows-in-data-frames-based-on-the-given-parameter/62417348#62417348)

I tried below code, but that is giving me the desired output.

```
# function to create the u_cumulative
def create_u_columns (ser, threshold_ns = 0.8):
    # create a copy
    arr_ns = ser.to_numpy().copy()
    # array for latter insert
    arr_idx = np.zeros(len(ser), dtype=int)
    walkin_id = 0 #start at 0 not 1 for list indexing
    for i in range(len(arr_ns)-1):
        if arr_ns[i]>threshold_ns:
            # remove 1 - walkin
            arr_ns[i+1:] -= (1-walkin_no_show[walkin_id])
            # increment later idx to add
            arr_idx[i] = walkin_id+1
            walkin_id +=1
    # for the last row
    if arr_ns[-1]>threshold_ns:
        arr_idx[-1] = walkin_id+1
    #return a dataframe with both columns
    return pd.DataFrame({'u_cumulative': arr_ns, 'mask_idx':arr_idx}, index=ser.index)
```

Now define another function overbook_dfs

```
def overbook_dfs (df0, walkin_no_show, threshold_p ):
        l_res = [] #for result
        for th_p in threshold_p: #loop on threshold
            # create a copy of original dataframe
            df = df0.copy() 
            df[['u_cumulative','mask_idx']] = create_u_columns(df['Cumulative_no_show'],
                                                               threshold_ns=th_p)
            # select the rows
            df_toAdd = df.loc[df['mask_idx'].astype(bool), :].copy()
            # replace the values as wanted
            df_toAdd['No_Show'] = walkin_no_show[:len(df_toAdd)]
            df_toAdd['B_ID'] = 'walkin'+df_toAdd['mask_idx'].astype(str)
            df_toAdd['u_cumulative'] -= (1 - df_toAdd['No_Show'])
            # add 0.5 to index for later sort
            df_toAdd.index += 0.5 
            #append the result to a list
            l_res.append(pd.concat([df,df_toAdd])
                           .sort_index()
                           .reset_index(drop=True)
                           .drop('mask_idx', axis=1)
                        )
        return l_res
```

Finally, use it with the parameters

```
# parameters
walkin_no_show = [ 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 0.7, 0.8]
threshold_p = [0.8, 0.9, 1.0, 1.1]

# call your function
df_0_8, df_0_9, df_1_0, df_1_1 = overbook_dfs(df, walkin_no_show, threshold_p)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution adapted for this case. There are small changes:

- in `create_u_columns`, `arr_idx` is replaced by a list of list `l_idx` that will contains all the walkin numbers if several per row, the `if` condition in the loop for is replaced by a `while`
- in `overlook_dfs`, instead of using df['mask_idx'].astype(bool) to select the rows to add, you need to `explode` the lists in the column `mask_idx` now (result from the change in `create_u_columns`) and dropna remove the rows without row to add after.

Otherwise it is pretty similar

```
def create_u_columns (ser, threshold_ns = 0.8):
    # create a copy
    arr_ns = ser.to_numpy().copy()
    # use a list of list instead of array
    l_idx = [[] for i in range(len(ser))]
    walkin_id = 0
    for i in range(len(arr_ns)-1):
        ## need the value as another varaible for the while method
        val = arr_ns[i]
        while val>threshold_ns: ## while instead of if
            # remove 1 - walkin
            arr_ns[i+1:] -= (1-walkin_no_show[walkin_id])
            val -= (1-walkin_no_show[walkin_id]) # to stop the while
            # increment later idx to add
            walkin_id +=1
            l_idx[i].append(walkin_id)
    # for the last row
    if arr_ns[-1]>threshold_ns:
        l_idx[-1].append(walkin_id+1)
    #return a dataframe with both columns
    return pd.DataFrame({'u_cumulative': arr_ns, 'mask_idx':l_idx}, 
                        index=ser.index)
```

And

```
def overbook_dfs (df0, walkin_no_show, threshold_p ):
    l_res = [] #for result
    for th_p in threshold_p: #loop on threshold
        # create a copy of original dataframe
        df = df0.copy() 
        df[['u_cumulative','mask_idx']] = create_u_columns(df['Cumulative_no_show'], 
                                                           threshold_ns=th_p)
        # select the rows by explode the column mask_idx and dropna
        df_toAdd = df.explode('mask_idx').dropna().copy() ###this is different
        # replace the values as wanted
        df_toAdd['No_Show'] = walkin_no_show[:len(df_toAdd)]
        df_toAdd['B_ID'] = 'walkin'+df_toAdd['mask_idx'].astype(str)
        df_toAdd['u_cumulative'] -= (1 - df_toAdd['No_Show'])
        # add 0.5 to index for later sort
        df_toAdd.index += 0.5 
        #append the result to a list
        l_res.append(pd.concat([df,df_toAdd])
                       .sort_index()
                       .reset_index(drop=True)
                       .drop('mask_idx', axis=1)
                    )
    return l_res

# parameter
walkin_no_show = [ 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 0.7, 0.8]
threshold_p = [0.8, 0.9, 1.0, 1.1]

# call your function
df_0_8, df_0_9, df_1_0, df_1_1 = overbook_dfs(df, walkin_no_show, threshold_p)
```

and you get for example

```
print (df_0_9)
       B_ID  No_Show Session  slot_num  Cumulative_no_show  u_cumulative
0         1      0.4      s1         1                 0.4           0.4
1         2      0.3      s1         2                 0.7           0.7
2         3      0.8      s1         3                 1.5           1.5
3   walkin1      0.3      s1         3                 1.5           0.8
4         4      0.3      s1         4                 1.8           1.1
5   walkin2      0.2      s1         4                 1.8           0.3
6         5      0.6      s1         5                 2.4           0.9
7         6      0.8      s1         6                 3.2           1.7
8   walkin3      0.1      s1         6                 3.2           0.8
9         7      0.9      s1         7                 4.1           1.7
10  walkin4      0.4      s1         7                 4.1           1.1
11  walkin5      0.5      s1         7                 4.1           1.2
12        8      0.4      s1         8                 4.5           1.0
13  walkin6      0.4      s1         8                 4.5           0.4
14        9      0.6      s1         9                 5.1           1.0
15  walkin7      0.2      s1         9                 5.1           0.2
```

Comment: pls look into this question if you have time, no one answered.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62889550/calculate-specific-function-from-the-date-column-and-input-parameter-specified-b

Comment: created new question, pls look into that during your free time. No one answered.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62959037/create-a-new-column-by-looping-over-list-of-dictionary-and-based-on-specific-dat

Comment: added new question pls look into this during your free time
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63560565/loop-over-the-given-dictionary-of-list-and-augment-the-given-input-dataframe-bas